# Representation and gauge transformation of Yang-Mills theory

Tags: gauge-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills

Let us consider a classical field theory with gauge fields $A_{\mu}^{a}$ and a scalar $\phi^{a}$ such that the Lagrangian is gauge-invariant under the transformation of

1. the gauge fields $A_{\mu}^{a}$ in the adjoint representation, with dimension $D_{\bf R}$, of the gauge group $SU(N)$, and
2. the scalar $\phi^{a}$ in the fundamental representation, with dimension $N$, of the gauge group $SU(N).$

---

1. Why can we represent $\phi$ as a traceless Hermitian $N \times N$ matrix, so that $\phi = \phi^{a}T^{a}$ where the $T^a$ are the representation matrices in the fundamental representation?
2. Why can we write down the variation of $\phi$ under a gauge transformation with gauge parameters $\theta^{a}$ as
   $$\delta\phi = ig[\theta^{a}T^{a},\phi]$$
   and the gauge covariant derivative as
   $$D_{\mu}\phi = \partial_{\mu}\phi - igA_{\mu}^{a}[T^{a},\phi]?$$

Comment: Which reference?

Comment: It seems that the post (v2) conflates fundamental, adjoint & bifundamental representations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a quantum field theorist, but I think you are mixing up stuffs, so I am gonna go through some elementary concepts (some of which you might already be familiar with).

The group $\text{SU}(N)$ is a *Lie-group*, eg. a group, which is also a smooth manifold in the sense, it is a set of continuum cardinality elements and it can be locally parametrized by $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\text{SU}(N)$ real parameters, in a way that two different parametrizations have smooth transition functions, and the *group operations* are smooth.

Such groups always admit an associated Lie-algebra, denoted as $\mathfrak{su}(N)$.

Now, $\text{SU}(N)$ is such a Lie-group, that while it exists "abstractly", it can be seen most naturally as the set of all $N\times N$ sized complex matrices, which satisfy $\Lambda^\dagger\Lambda=1$ *and* $\det\Lambda=1$. For such matrix Lie-groups, the Lie algebra can be seen as a set of $N\times N$ matrices too. These matrices are *tangent vectors at the identity*, meaning that if $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\text{SU}(N)$ is a smooth curve that goes through the identity at 0 ($\gamma(0)=1$), then $d\gamma/dt|_{t=0}$ is an element of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$.

We have $\gamma(t)\gamma^\dagger(t)=1$ for all $t$, so $$0=\frac{d}{dt}1= \frac{d}{dt}\gamma\gamma^\dagger|_{t=0}=\frac{d\gamma}{dt}|_{t=0}\gamma^\dagger(0)+\gamma(0)\frac{d\gamma^\dagger}{dt}|_{t=0}=\frac{d\gamma}{dt}|_{t=0}+\frac{d\gamma^\dagger}{dt}|_{t=0}=0, $$ so the elements of the Lie algebra are *antihermitian* matrices.

This is not the only condition though, because we also have the unit determinant condition.
We can obtain (from say [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)) that this condition also implies that $d\gamma/dt|_{t=0}$ has vanishing trace.

Conclusion: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ consists of *traceless, antihermitian matrices*. This set is closed under addition, scalar multiplication and also under commutators (so if $A,B\in\mathfrak{su}(N)$, then $[A,B]\in\mathfrak{su}(N)$).

Now, as convention dictates, we usually take the Lie algebra to consist of *hermitian* matrices instead of antihermitean ones, we can do this, because we can always convert an antihermitean matrix into a hermitean one by multiplying with $i$ (and vice versa).

---

Now to actually answer you question, that the scalar field $\phi^a$ is in the fundamental representation of $\text{SU}(N)$ means that the index $a$ ranges from 1 to $N$ and *if we view the $\text{SU}(N)$ elements as $N\times N$ matrices*, then they act on $\phi$ by $\phi^a\mapsto\Lambda^a_{\ b}\phi^b$.

Now let $A=(A^a_{\ b})$ be a matrix in $\mathfrak{su}(N)$, the Lie algebra. The adjoint representation of $\text{SU}(N)$ is when $\text{SU}(N)$ is represented on the Lie algebra itself by $A\mapsto\Lambda A\Lambda^{-1}\equiv \Lambda A\Lambda^\dagger$.

The dimension of $\text{SU}(N)$ is $N^2-1$, and the *Lie algebra has the same dimension*. Which means that the dimension of the representation space of the fundamental representation is $N$ but the dimension of the representation space of the adjoint representation is $N^2-1$, so you cannot use the same set of indices. Let $A,B,...$ take the values $1,...,N^2-1$.

The scalar field then looks like $\phi^a$ but the gauge field looks like $A^A_\mu$.

1) The scalar field cannot be written as you had written, since the indices $a$ and $A$ in general do not have the same range.

2) I don't know what is your source, but I have never ever seen a covariant derivative written like that. The point of the covariant derivative is that if you allow *point-dependent* gauge transformations on $\phi$, eg. you allow $\phi^a(x)\mapsto\Lambda^a_{\ b}(x)\phi^b(x)$, then the partial derivatives $\partial_\mu$ are **not** good differential operators on the space of $\phi$-fields, because it is not gauge-covariant.

Instead, if $x^\mu(\lambda)$ is a curve in spacetime, let's assume that the rate of change of $\phi^a$ can be split into two terms, a *physical* rate of change and a *gauge* rate of change: $$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}\phi^a=\frac{D}{d\lambda}\phi^a+\frac{\delta}{d\lambda}\phi^a, $$ and since $d\phi^a/d\lambda=\partial_\mu\phi^a\cdot dx^\mu/d\lambda$ by the chain rule, we also have $$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}\phi^a=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\phi^a\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\left(D_\mu\phi^a+\delta_\mu\phi^a\right). $$ It can be shown that the difference of two differential operators that act on real functions the same way is a linear transform, and we want the *physical* rate of change $D_\mu$ to act as a differential operator, $\delta_\mu$ must act as a linear transformation, so we have $\delta_\mu\phi^a=-\mathcal{A}_{\mu\ \ b}^{\ a}\phi^b$ for some linear transformation valued vector field $\mathcal{A}_{\mu\ \ b}^{\ a}$.

So we have $D_\mu\phi^a=\partial_\mu\phi^a+\mathcal{A}_{\mu\ \ b}^{\ a}\phi^b$.

But $\mathcal{A}$ must be $\mathfrak{su}(N)$-valued. Why? We say that along a curve $x^\mu(\lambda)$ the field $\phi^a$ is parallel transported, if $d\phi^a/d\lambda=-\mathcal{A}_{\mu\ \ b}^{\ a}\phi^b\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$, eg. the *physical* rate of change is zero.

The field $\phi^a$ at different points are incomparable, because of point-dependent gauge transformations, but let us take the curve $x^\mu(\lambda)$ to be a *closed* loop, and let us take a one-parameter family of such loops, $x^\mu(\lambda,\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon$ is a smooth parameter and for $\epsilon=0$, the loop is the trivial loop that stays at a point $p$ and doesn't go anywhere (so $\epsilon$ is a smallness parameter of the loop).

If we parallel transport $\phi^a$ along this loop, then the change in $\phi^a$ must be a gauge transformation, since the field did not change *physically*, so the difference is $\Lambda(x(\epsilon,\lambda))^a_{\ b}\phi(x)^b-\phi^a(x)$ where $\lambda$ is the endpoint parameter of the loop. The gauge transformation for small $\epsilon$s is then $\Lambda(x(\epsilon,\lambda))=1+\epsilon B(\lambda,\epsilon)$ where $B$ is an element of the Lie algebra, since it is infinitesimally close to the identity.

Now calculating the rate of change of $\phi$ gives $$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}\phi^a=\frac{d}{d\lambda}(1+\epsilon B^a_{\ b}\phi^b)=\epsilon \frac{d}{d\lambda}B^a_{\ b}\phi^b=-\mathcal{A}_{\mu\ \ b}^{\ a}\phi^b \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} $$ and from this we can see that $\mathcal{A}$ must be Lie algebra valued. Then, to switch to hermitean matrices instead of antihermitean ones, we define $igA_\mu=\mathcal{A}_\mu$, and if $\{T_A\}_{A=1}^{N^2-1}$ is a basis for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(N)$, we have $$ D_\mu\phi=\partial_\mu\phi+igA_\mu^AT_A\phi. $$